# Remote repository not creating branch when I push

Tags: git, push

I tried to push a new branch to my remote repository on github. I get the error message 'failed to push some ref to 'https://github.com/tararoys/SurveyDBC.git'

```
git push -u origin TLR/Refactoring-Practice
error: src refspec TLR/Refactoring-Practice does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/tararoys/SurveyDBC.git'
Taras-MacBook-Air:SurveyDBCGroupProject tlroys$ git push -u origin TLR-Refactoring-Practice
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command only works if the name of your remote branch is exactly the same as the name of your local branch.

```
 git push -u origin TLR/Refactoring-Practice
```

does not work because the local branch name has a dash between TLR and Refactoring, not a backslash.

```
 git push -u origin TLR/Refactoring-Practice #does not work
 git push -u origin TLR-Refactoring-Practice #works
```

You can rename the remote branch. In order to do that, the command would be

```
git push -u origin TLR-Refactoring-Practice:TLR/Refactoring-Practice
```

This names the remote branch TLR/Refactoring-Practice.